# Which Alcohol is fine with upset stomach?

Tags: digestion, alcohol, stomach

I have a sensitive stomach and it gets disturbed by outside food quite soon. Currently it just got over it (no alcohol involved yet) but I might have a party soon with unavoidable liqueur, so I wanted to know which alcohol I can have with bad stomach. I like beer, whiskey and rum but open for a change if ti help my stomach.

<sub>*My stomach sensitivity is towards extra oily food or heavy food.</sub>

Comment: are you sure about the fact that liquor is _unavoidable_ at the party?